# What's an example of a theory that's consistent yet has no model?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

By the completeness theorem for first order logic, if a theory is consistent then it has a model.

But what's a counterexample to this : what's an example of a logic where some theory is consistent yet has no model?

More specifically, I want to know about second order logic... Since from what I understand the completeness theorem does not apply to it, what would be an example of a consistent second order theory which has no model?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take the second-theory in the language of $\leq$ which states that:

1. $(A,\leq)$ is a linear order without a maximal element.
2. Every non-empty set has a minimal element.
3. Every bounded set has a maximal element.

This means that $(A,\leq)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ with its usual order. Now add uncountably many constant symbols to the language $c_i$ for $i\in I$, and add the axioms $c_i\neq c_j$ for each $i\neq j$.

Of course this theory cannot have a model, since a model would be isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ but it will have uncountably many elements. But given any finite number of axioms we can interpret them in the usual order on $\Bbb N$, so they cannot possible prove a contradiction. Therefore the theory is consistent.

---

If you don't want to use an uncountable language, add $c_i$ for $i\in\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb N$, and claim that $c_i<c_j$ whenever $i<j$. Again finitely many axioms are interpretable in the usual $\Bbb N$ showing consistency, but there is no model which is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ and is not well-ordered.

If you don't want to use an infinite language, just add one constant symbol, $c$ and axioms that say that $c$ is not the minimal element, not the successor of the minimal element, and so on and so forth (note that the successor function is definable in $\Bbb N$ with $\leq$, even in first-order logic). The same argument from above applies.

Comment: @MJD: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: There are perhaps easier ways to get a theory with only countable full models, e.g. the axioms "The universe is infinite" and "For each infinite subset of the universe there is a bijection between it and the entire universe."

Comment: @Carl, that might be simpler, I don't know. I always found "some structure" to be simpler when trying to show and understand categoricity.

Comment: @Asaf I have trouble seeing how a theory with different axioms than natural numbers is isomorphic to the natural numbers, yet been different enough to require a different model. What is the definition of isomorphic in this context?

Comment: @Alexandre: It means what you think it means. I don't see how this is "different". This is just a second order way of characterizing the natural numbers as an ordered set.

Comment: @Asaf I agree that (A,≤) as you defined it is isomorphic to the natural numbers. But as soon as you add another axiom then I would think you lose the isomorphism since the natural numbers are not able to reproduce this axiom. Then you claim "Of course this theory cannot have a model, since a model would be isomorphic to ℕ but it will have uncountably many elements.". But, if it has uncountably many elements, it is not isomorphic to the natural numbers, and would be something else.

Comment: @Alexandre: It is a theory which is finitely consistent, but has no model. That's the point.

Comment: @Asaf ok, so i am assuming that c is a natural number added to the theory with properties that make it such that it cannot exist. Then it is claimed that no contradiction can otherwise be obtained from the axioms, hence the theory is consistent but has no model. So it is equivalent to saying the theory does not contradict itself, but it does contradict reality.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want a general logic where a theory is syntactically consistent but has no model, start with the usual first-order logic, but consider the semantics where we have only *finite* models. There are many consistent theories that have only infinite models; in our new logic these theories will be consistent but will have no models at all.

That example has the same issue as second-order logic, actually. The completeness theorem for second-order logic does not hold ***if*** we use a particular semantics, known as full semantics. The point of full semantics is that it excludes *by fiat* many models that would otherwise satisfy second-order theories, just like our first-order logic with only finite models.

Intuitively, it is easy to see why this would cause the completeness theorem to fail: the completeness theorem says that every consistent theory has a model *in the general sense*. But if we start to reduce the set of "allowable" models, we may well exclude all the models of some particular theory. The theory will still be syntactically consistent - it hasn't changed at all!

We can find examples of theories with no full model by taking theories that are syntactically incomplete, but which have only one full model. For example, there is an axiomatization $T$ of arithmetic with the property that its only full model is the standard model. If we take $T + \lnot\text{Con}(T)$, this will be consistent by Goedel's incompleteness theorem, but it will have no full model.

I have written something else about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203299/are-there-non-standard-models-of-arithmetic-in-second-order-arithmetic/203408#203408).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Btw, and a bit off topic, do you know where I can find a self contained and relatively short (like a couple of pages maximum), but detailed, proof of the syntactic version of the incompleteness theorem? Preferably available online..