# Finitely axiomatized second-order theory without a model, which is consistent for reasonable deductive systems

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, model-theory, second-order-logic

This is a follow-up question on [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2277613/415941), where I asked for an example for a *finitely axiomatizable consistent second-order theory without a model*. It was pointed out that this can not be answered objectively without me stating a concrete deductive system for second-order logic (there is no standard one like in FOL).

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1005292/415941) answer (which I also mentioned in my previous question), Asaf gave a consistent second-order theory without a model, *but* with an axiom schema, hence not finitely axiomized. But he also never mentioned any deductive system. Instead he proved (implicitely) that his example is consistent w.r.t. any *reasonable* deductive system. Reasonable means:

- compact: proves are finite, hence can only use finitely many axioms.
- sound: we can only deduce true sentences.

So here is an update to my former question:

> Is there an example of a finitely axiomatized second-order theory without a model that is consistent w.r.t. any reasonable (i.e. compact + sound) deductive system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, though perhaps only because your criteria for "reasonable" are too weak.  Consider the following "deductive system".  Given a set of axioms $\Gamma$, a sentence $\sigma$ can be deduced from $\Gamma$ if there exists a finite subset $\Gamma_0$ such that $\sigma$ is true in every model of $\Gamma_0$.  This is compact and sound, but clearly a finite set of axioms is consistent with respect to this system iff it has a model.

More generally, even if you strengthen your definition of reasonable somehow, consider the following argument.  Suppose you had a finite set of axioms $\Gamma$ which has no model but which is consistent with respect to any "reasonable" deductive system.  Now take your favorite "reasonable" deductive system and strengthen it by adding a new inference rule that allows you to deduce a contradiction from $\Gamma$.  This new deductive system breaks your example $\Gamma$, so it cannot be "reasonable".  So if you want such a $\Gamma$ to exist, "reasonable" deductive systems must not be closed under adding one additional sound inference rule of this sort.